# Gaussian elimination has to give back multiple solutions php

Tags: php, matrix, gaussian

I want to use gaussian elimination to solve the following matrix [Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elsN1.png) and this is the [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFZ5q.png) I'm expecting. I would like to get back an equation in the form as is displayed in answer but i can't figure out how to do it.

```
public function gauss($A, $x) {
    # Just make a single matrix
    for ($i=0; $i < count($A); $i++) {
        $A[$i][] = $x[$i];
    }
    $n = count($A);

    for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        # Search for maximum in this column
        $maxEl = abs($A[$i][$i]);
        $maxRow = $i;
        for ($k=$i+1; $k < $n; $k++) {
            if (abs($A[$k][$i]) > $maxEl) {
                $maxEl = abs($A[$k][$i]);
                $maxRow = $k;
            }
        }


        # Swap maximum row with current row (column by column)
        for ($k=$i; $k < $n+1; $k++) {
            $tmp = $A[$maxRow][$k];
            $A[$maxRow][$k] = $A[$i][$k];
            $A[$i][$k] = $tmp;
        }

        # Make all rows below this one 0 in current column
        for ($k=$i+1; $k < $n; $k++) {
            $c = -$A[$k][$i]/$A[$i][$i];
            for ($j=$i; $j < $n+1; $j++) {
                if ($i==$j) {
                    $A[$k][$j] = 0;
                } else {
                    $A[$k][$j] += $c * $A[$i][$j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # Solve equation Ax=b for an upper triangular matrix $A
    $x = array_fill(0, $n, 0);
    for ($i=$n-1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $x[$i] = $A[$i][$n]/$A[$i][$i];
        for ($k=$i-1; $k > -1; $k--) {
            $A[$k][$n] -= $A[$k][$i] * $x[$i];
        }
    }

    return $x;
}
```

I hope someone can help me to rewrite this code so it gives the solution i've provided or recommend a library which is capable of doing this.
I've searched for possible solutions on Google but haven't been able to find one yet.

Thanks in advance.